# Vue js Cli app running in another computer

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I would like to share my Vue js application project which is in my repository with a friend. So I used vue-cli, npm/yarn and webpack to develope.
I would like to know if he needs to install also cli to run the app on his computer, or just npm install and npm run? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `vue-cli` is not strictly necessary. However, if you're used to using `vue build` to build & run your app, your friend might want that too. He/she could just use some other way to run the webpack build operation if installing `vue-cli` isn't an option.